# Any idea why IE8 won't let me target nested elements using their id and class name with CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have website whose home-page's body has a class name: .homepage

Inside the body there is a div with an id: #content.

I just want to give the homepage's #content div a background image with CSS like this:

```
.homepage #content {
background: #FFFFFF url("image.jpg") no-repeat scroll 90% 30px;
}
```

This works in all browsers apart from IE8 backwards. It works in IE9.

In IE8, No image appears.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a workaround?

Comment: I assume `.hompage` is a typo as it shouldn't work in any browser.

Comment: @Toner: if #content is an id, then you could remove the .homepage, as id should be unique in a webpage.

Comment: @Micheal, not if the OP wants to target content just for the homepage.

Comment: @jason, yeah that was a type - fixed.

Comment: @michael, just like jason says. I just want to target the homepage's #content div. That div is on all pages of the site.

Comment: I see you fixed placing the color too. Deleted my answer.

Comment: So is that the exact CSS rule? This is different from before...

Comment: @jason, yeah I just switched the hex code to the front exactly as I have it in the stylesheet. Previously I copied it from firebug where it pushes it to the end of the rule.

Comment: @Toner: Try the IE8 Developer Tools add-on and see what that says.

Comment: @jason, I did but that rule doesn't show up, I assume because it does not recognize it but I admit to not being as familiar with developer tools as firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it.

Try `background:red;` then `background:red url(image.jpg)` and slowly add on values until it works.

If neither works, check for conflicting rules in IE stylesheets. Also try `!important`

Comment: I went ahead and did this and discovered that in my original rule, I did not place a space after the URL and before 'no-repeat'. This is why it did not show in IE8. Thanks to everyone who tried to help. My mistake. I did not know a space was necessary after the closing parenthesis and before 'no-repeat'.

Answer (score 0):

Test it without the "scroll" property and see if the image appears.